# Nested flex containers overflowing in Firefox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm working on a web-app that utilizes UI-Router and many nested views. Our main views use Flex to take up all available space on the screen (both height and width). I say this to identify why we have so many nested flex containers.

**TL;DR;**

[JSFiddle showing the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/rL0r8nez/4/)

On IE and Chrome, the following JSFiddle works the way you would expect. All outer divs fit to the page, while the innermost div has a scrollbar for the overflowing content inside.

On Firefox the scrollbar is on the body, or one of the outer divs, and the containers don't really work at all.

I need consistent behavior across all browsers, any ideas?

**Longer explanation:**

Our app works great on Chrome and IE10+, but on Firefox the flex containers just don't seem to work the way we need them too. Our intention is for the lowermost flex container to have overflow auto and for the rest of them to simply fit to the screen without scroll bars.

I've tried to ensure we're using all cross browser flex prefixes, so when we declare a flex container (using LESS mixins) the result is this:

```
display: -webkit-box; /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
display: -moz-box; /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
display: -ms-flexbox; /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
display: -webkit-flex; /* NEW - Chrome */
display: flex; /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
width: 100%; /* For old syntax, otherwise collapses. */
```

And when we declare something to flex, this is the output:

```
-webkit-box-flex: 1; /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
-moz-box-flex: 1; /* OLD - Firefox 19- */
-webkit-flex: 1; /* Chrome */
-ms-flex: 1; /* IE 10 */
flex: 1; /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
```

This results in many nested flex containers working beautiful on IE and Chrome, but Firefox does wacky things. On IE/Chrome, the inner-most container contains the overflow and puts a scrollbar where it's needed, while firefox either doesn't contain it at all or puts the scrollbar on the outer most container. Looks like firefox isn't honoring the flex at all hardly.

I need consistent behavior across all browsers, any ideas? This needs to be a pure css solution as I'm too far into the project to change my HTML structure all that much.

[JSFiddle showing the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/rL0r8nez/4/)

**UPDATE**

I tried the below implementation and it did not work, unfortunately. I believe the difference is that in my top level container there is a sidebar, which makes the rest of the example a little different. I apologize for not including this detail originally as it was obviously important.

Here are two additional fiddles, with (I think) a better representation of the scenarios.

Using `flex: 1;`

[JSFiddle for flex 1](https://jsfiddle.net/rL0r8nez/7/)

You'll notice this works great in IE11 and Chrome, but bombs on Firefox.

Using `flex: auto;`

[JS Fiddle for flex auto](https://jsfiddle.net/rL0r8nez/8/)

This doesn't work in anything...

Answer (score 0):

Change all of your `flex:1` to `flex:auto` I'm pretty sure that's what you're after.

css:

```
html, body
{
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.outer-container {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 4px solid #00f;
    display: -webkit-box; /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
    display: -moz-box; /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
    display: -ms-flexbox; /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
    display: -webkit-flex; /* NEW - Chrome */
    display: flex; /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
    width: 100%; /* For old syntax, otherwise collapses. */
    height: 100%;
}
.container {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 4px solid #0ff;
    display: -webkit-box; /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
    display: -moz-box; /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
    display: -ms-flexbox; /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
    display: -webkit-flex; /* NEW - Chrome */
    display: flex; /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
    width: 100%; /* For old syntax, otherwise collapses. */
    -webkit-box-flex: auto; /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
    -moz-box-flex: auto; /* OLD - Firefox 19- */
    -webkit-flex: auto; /* Chrome */
    -ms-flex: auto; /* IE 10 */
    flex: auto; /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
}
.inner-container {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 4px solid #f0f;
    -webkit-box-flex: auto; /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
    -moz-box-flex: auto; /* OLD - Firefox 19- */
    -webkit-flex: auto; /* Chrome */
    -ms-flex: auto; /* IE 10 */
    flex: auto; /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */    
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
.overflow {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 4px solid #f00;
    height: 100px;
    width: 900px;
}
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/rL0r8nez/5/

Comment: Danged if I didn't think I'd tried that already. I'll have to plug that in and see what will work with it. Certainly fixes the problem. Can you explain why?

Comment: Sure! When you use `flex:1` or `flex-basis:1`, you are essentially saying that you want your elements to take up the same amount of space regardless of content (this is very general and how I understand it). When you say `flex:auto`, you are saying let the content of each *individual* element dictate the space it takes up. If this works for you, can you please mark it as the accepted answer? Good luck! EDIT: here's a good break down: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp

Comment: Unfortunately no, updated the post. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you set `.container {max-width: 100%;}`  on your example with `flex: 1;`, you then get the inner scrollbar in firefox.